# In Woocommerce -Redirect to shop page after removing last item from the cart page when item is removed through ajax

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to redirect page to shop page when last item removed from cart in woocommerce using ajax?

I am tried below code:

```
function cartitem_after_remove_product($cart_item_key) {
    global $woocommerce;
     $total_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
     if($total_count == 0)
     {
         wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
     }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'cartitem_after_remove_product' );
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried

Comment: now you can show above code

Comment: @BInjalPatel Please Check Latest Ans Post by me...

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this code into you function.php file (your theme):

```
function cart_empty_redirect_to_shop() {
  global $woocommerce, $woocommerce_errors;

if ( is_cart() && sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) === 0) { 
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) ); 
     exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'cart_empty_redirect_to_shop' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Javascript. WooCommerce has several custom events built in. Your own script can listen to these events and run your own code when they are triggered. One idea would be to check for the class "cart-empty" on updated_cart_totals.

```
$( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
  // Check for empty class
  if ( $('div.woocommerce-info').hasClass( "cart-empty" ) ) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/shop/";
  }
});
```